# How to disable logs in Netty 4?

Tags: logging, log4j, netty

How can I disable all logs Netty 4 does with log4j?
I actually want to write all logs by myself and see only in logs only what I wrote there.
I'm new to both Netty and log4j.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the line listed below helped me to turn off Netty logs. I don't know if it disables all possible logs from Netty, but at least those I'd already saw.

```java
Logger.getLogger("io.netty").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @DWand did not work for me, but something similar did work in the case of Hibernate:

```java
Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(...)
```

For Netty, I simply used a class-based config, and set a name filter to the log handler along with some other conditions:

```java
handler.setFilter(record -> !record.getLoggerName().startsWith("io.netty"))
```

I am not sure if this is a good way to do it, but this was the only way I could skip *only* Netty logs.

Comment: can you be more specific on how to get this working?

Comment: @Raksha, are you using a log config file or class? I am not sure about whether or not you can do this with a file alone. Using class allowed me to set custom filter to block any loggers that start with the name "io.netty".

Answer (score 0):

If you work with

```
src/main/resources/log4j.properties
```

Add

```
log4j.logger.io.netty=OFF
```